# Does this Lear 35 have missiles on it?

Tags: aircraft-identification

*Janes aircraft recognition guide* has a picture of this plane on the Lear 35 page. Does it have missiles on it or is this some special modification?

[image: lear 35]

Comment: Further photos on http://www.airliners.net/search/photo.search?regsearch=N83FN have more comments, one of which say "30 year old Lear loaded with ACM pods to simulate fighter/missile attacks on surface ships".

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No, it's not a missile, it's a towed target:

[image]

[Towed targets](http://www2.l-3com.com/fi/towed_devices.htm) are used for [electronic warfare](http://media.defenceindustrydaily.com/images/AIR_Learjet_L-3_with_EW_Stores_lg.jpg) and gunnery [training](http://www.defenseindustrydaily.com/lease-and-learn-l-3s-ew-training-aircraft-05378/). The can serve as a radar target or visual target during military exercises.

The 'missile' is on a long cord and can be reeled from the aircraft. The pod that you see here is a [MTR-101 reeling system](http://www.airaffairs.com.au/reeling_machine.html) with the capability to drag the target up to 30,000 ft behind the aircraft.

If you are interested in flying these kind of missions, it seems  L3 is looking for a new [First Officer](http://www.linkedin.com/jobs2/view/12786575) for their Learjets.

Comment: This raises the further question "Do aircraft towing targets ever get shot down?" or are we just talking about targeting practice as opposed to target practice.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently yes. Googling for the tail number turns up [more](http://www.airliners.net/search/photo.search?regsearch=N83FN) [pictures](http://www.myaviation.net/search/search.php?view=&regnr=N83FN), as well as comments saying this particular plane is "used to simulate missile attacks".

[Here is the owning company](http://www2.l-3com.com/fi/Services.htm), a defense contractor that among other things provides simulated air attacks for training exercises.

Comment: uh, no. The word SIMULATED says it all. They're not missiles.